How to decrease by 1 integers in an expl3's clist?
I have (what I want to be considered as) integers in a comma separated list (clist) that I want all to be decreased by 1. Unfortunately the items contained in this list look to not be considered as integers since the following MCE:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 1, 15, 25, 47 }
\clist_map_variable:NNn \l_tmpa_clist \l_tmpa_int {
  \int_decr:N \l_tmpa_int
}
\clist_show:N \l_tmpa_clist
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}

leads to the error:
! You can't use `the character 1' after \advance.
\l_tmpa_int ->1

If I understand well, the items contained in this clist look to be considered as token lists but I couldn't find in interface3.pdf a way to convert them into integers.

Within the mapping, you should not alter the value of the variable. You also (more or less) can't modify the mapped variable in the loop. Instead, you need to make a copy:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 1, 15, 25, 47 }
\clist_clear:N \l_tmpb_clist
\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 
  {
    \clist_put_right:Ne \l_tmpb_clist { \int_eval:n { #1 - 1 } }
  }
\clist_show:N \l_tmpb_clist
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}


The documentation says that the second argument to \clist_map_variable:NNn should be a token list variable.
When the loop begins, \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {1} will be executed (and TeX doesn't complain, because \tl_set:Nn is basically \def (not really, but the semplification is harmless); next you instruct TeX to do \int_decr:N \l_tmpa_int which cannot work, because \l_tmpa_int is no longer a TeX counter and, at the deepest level, the assignment
\advance \l_tmpa_int by -1

is tried. Since \advance performs macro expansion, TeX will find
\advance 1 by -1

and the error you mention comes up.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l__db_clist_incr_aux_clist

\cs_new_protected:Nn \db_clist_incr:Nn
 {% #1 = clist variable, #2 = increment
  \clist_set_eq:NN \l__db_clist_incr_aux_clist #1
  \clist_clear:N #1
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__db_clist_incr_aux_clist
   {
    \clist_put_right:Ne #1 { \int_eval:n { ##1 + (#2) } }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
  


\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 1, 15, 25, 47 }
\db_clist_incr:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {-1}
\clist_show:N \l_tmpa_clist

\db_clist_incr:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {3}
\clist_show:N \l_tmpa_clist

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}

You get
The comma list \l_tmpa_clist contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {0}
>  {14}
>  {24}
>  {46}.
<recently read> }

l.27 \clist_show:N \l_tmpa_clist

?
The comma list \l_tmpa_clist contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {3}
>  {17}
>  {27}
>  {49}.
<recently read> }

l.30 \clist_show:N \l_tmpa_clist

